# Installation issue under Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, g-wan

Is anyone gettings success to run G-WAN on Debian Wheezy?

I am trying to use G-WAN for testing with future full move to it. I enjoy doing my websites lightweight and loading extremely faster. Today i need native and multi-threaded (like G-WAN's) solution for scripting lanquages like PHP. G-WAN is perfect. I review it's website and find their creators very advanced users). This is my one-core VDS for testing purposes (however it's completely cleaned and using latest semi-stable technologies).

Linux Others 3.2.0-4-486 #1 Debian 3.2.35-2 i686 GNU/Linux

I got installed glibc-2.13-1, libc-dev, openjdk-7-jdk, libsqlite3-dev, php5-cli. I want to test G-WAN so i don't need another lanquages to support for now.

I removed two files: tidy.c and tidy__.c however i don't think the problem in them.

In 'trace' i have: `Tue, 01 Jan 2013 04:18:48 GMT: start`

Error log (Seg Fault):

The code is not accepted by this website. I am not able to manually write symbols at every line of the copied code. Here's a link to the code:

http://pastebin.com/JAaH53DE

P.S. Sorry i am new here. Idk how to correctly paste code. I find it stupid to add custom code to any line of the code also why spaces should and can define some code syntax.

OFK: If exists any other resource where i can receive little support for G-WAN is would be perfect if someone mention it!

Comment: As said below, G-WAN v4 'resolves' GLIBC incompatibilities by removing its dependency on it. Note that for crash reports, the /log/gwan/log file is more useful than the terminal output that you provided.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested PHP with G-WAN but as reported in previous G-WAN threads here in SO there has been stability issues with the latest release.

My suggestion is empty your csp folder and only create a very simple C/C++ script first. Then run gwan with sudo. In my standard Linux Mint, C scripts work fine.

Comment: The stability issues with v3.12 are due to **GLIBC wrappers** and **direct syscalls** aiming at providing GLIBC version compatibility - clearly not the way to do that as GLIBC break horribly then. We are experimenting with static linking to achieve the compatibility feature without the unwanted detrimental side-effects.

Comment: Hello. My issue is not related to PHP. I removed csp directory. When i run ./gwan - it still said 'Segmentation Fault' after 3 sec. If this issue have something to do with glibc then to what version should i upgrade/degrade? Thx in advance.

Comment: Which version of eglibc is needed to run G-WAN without seg fault? At least can you tell me ANY version of eglibc where latest G-WAN run without Seg Fault?

Comment: GLIBC and its derivatives (ie: EGLIBC) have been abandonned for the affordmentioned reasons (even a Linux update with back ports or fixes can break GLIBC-based applications and libraries). G-WAN v4 (shipped in a few days) embeds a tiny runtime to avoid those unecessary uncertainties about the *system*, its *capabilities*, and its *performances*.